# What is the probability of getting red marbles from bag B?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

So there are 3 bags: bag A, bag B, and bag C.

1. Bag A contains 2 red marbles and 3 white marbles.
2. Bag B contains 3 red marbles and 5 white marbles.
3. Bag C contains 4 red marbles and 6 white marbles.

Suppose a bag was randomly selected and marble was taken out.
What is the probability of taking a red marble from bag B?

So I've tried the conditional probability
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSEky.png, but kinda confused.
If we make it like $P(A)$ is the probability of bag B chosen out of 3 bags and $P(A ∩ B)$ is the probability of getting red marbles out of marbles in bag B, making $P(A | B)$ the result.
But if we make it like $P(A)$ is the probability of red marbles get chosen out of all marbles, and $P(A | B)$ is the probability of only red marbles from bag B get chosen out of all marbles and making $P(A ∩ B)$ the result, it's going to be different. Which one is the right calculation (or maybe both are wrong...)?

Comment: I'd suggest using Bayes' Theorem for this.

Comment: As stated, the problem can be expressed as follows.  Let $E_1$ be the event that bag 2 is chosen.  Let $E_2$ be the event that a red marble is chosen.  What is the probability of events $E_1$ and $E_2$ both occurring?  **However**, I question whether the OP intended a **different** question: what is the probability of event $E_1$ occurring **given** that event $E_2$ occurred?  That is, what is $p(E_1|E_2)$?  I think that it would be helpful if the OP **clarified** which question he is asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a funny situation.  Considering my comment, while the OP has clearly shown work, I am still not sure which question is being asked.

So I will answer each question separately.

> Bag A contains 2 red marbles and 3 white marbles.
> Bag B contains 3 red marbles and 5 white marbles.
> Bag C contains 4 red marbles and 6 white marbles.

Let $E_1$ be the event that bag B is chosen. 
Let $E_2$ be the event that a red marble is chosen.

Q1: Compute $p(E_2 | E_1)$. 
Q2: Compute $p(E_1 ~\text{and} ~E_2 ~\text{both occurring})$. 
Q3: Compute $p(E_1 | E_2)$.

Answer-1: 
Given that bag B is chosen, the answer is immediately seen to be $\frac{3}{8}$.

Answer-2:
$p(E_1 ~\text{and} ~E_2 ~\text{both occurring})$ is (using Answer-1)

$$p(E_1) \times p(E_2|E_1) = \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{3}{8} = \frac{1}{8}.$$

Answer-3:
$$p(E_2) = \left[\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{2}{5}\right] 
+ \left[\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{3}{8}\right]
+ \left[\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{4}{10}\right]
= \frac{47}{120}.
$$

Using Answer-2,

$$p(E_1 | E_2) = \frac{p(E_1 ~\text{and} ~E_2 ~\text{both occurring})}{p(E_2)}$$

$$= \frac{(1/8)}{(47/120)} = \frac{15}{47}.$$